# MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter isn't using the ObjectMapper configured by a @Bean

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

i am using `spring-boot` 3.0.2 and have created a custom jackson serializer and registered it using `@JsonComponent`. i have confirmed it is registered in the `ObjectMapper` instance that gets injected using `@Autowire`. when i go to invoke the rest endpoint that will return an object that should be handled by the custom serializer, it is never by the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

after doing some digging it seems only the default set of converters created in `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` are being used and nothing else. i have tried registering my own instance of `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` as a `@Bean` but it is never used.

the only way i have found to fix this issue is to replace whatever default is being created using `extendMessageConverters` in `WebMvcConfigurer`.

can anyone offer any suggestions? from the various blog posts i've read, this should just work but appears not to.

i expect json that looks like this:

`["fqdn":"test.com"]`

but instead get:

```
["fqdn:{"idnEncoded":false,"domainName":"test","tldName":"com"}]
```